# PHP form validation passes even though there is error

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to develop a form validation system. But the problem is even though there is no data given by users as required the validation passes. Can't figure out where the problem is.

This is my form validation class

```
 class Validation
 {

private $_passed = false,
        $_errors = array(),
        $_db = null;

public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }
public function check($source, $items= array()) {
        foreach ($items as $item => $rules) {
            foreach ($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {
                $value = $source[$item];

                if ($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                    $this->addError("{$item} is required");
                } else {

                }
            }
        }

        if (empty($this->_errors)) {
            $this->_passed = true;
        }
        return $this;

    }

private function addError($error) {
        $this->errors[] = $error;
    }
public function errors() {
        return $this->_errors;
    }
public function passed() {
        return $this->_passed;
    }
 }
```

And this is the form page containing Html form.

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

if (Input::exists()) {
    $validate = new Validation();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
            ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
            ),
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
            ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 60
            ),
        ));
    if ($validation->passed()) {
        //register new user
        echo "passed"; //this passes even though users provides no data
    } else {
        print_r($validation->errors());
    }
}
```

So, all i get is echo **passed** on the screen even though user provide no data at all. It should throw the errors instead. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addError` writes in `$this->errors`, while the other methods use `$this->_errors`. (with underscore). The `_errors` array will remain empty, so `_passed` will be set to true in this statement:

```
if (empty($this->_errors)) {
    $this->_passed = true;
}
```

Comment: A bug like this can easily be found. Even without fancy tools like xdebug. `_passed` is set to true in only one place, and only when `_errors` is empty. `_errors` is also written to in just one place, and that place is exactly where the error was. You may use `var_dump` to show detailed information about variables and their contents.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just moving fast and checked typos for a while but couldn't found anything. I will take your notes. Appreciate your help